# No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to print a list of values in `ListView` from a webpage. I have the two permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

However I'm getting this message,

```
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
```

I'm not sure what it means and how to fixed.

Comment: This is not a problem. Follow this answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41365334/networksecurityconfig-no-network-security-config-specified-android-7-0-error

Comment: I already saw that question but It doesn't help me. I still have the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No Network Security Config specified, using platform default.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933345/no-network-security-config-specified-using-platform-default)

Answer (score 4):

The message you're getting isn't an error; it's just letting you know that you're not using a Network Security Configuration. If you want to add one, take a look at this page on the Android Developers website: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and after debugging it further, I found it a thread issue. I changed `onCreate` method as below and it works fine. No playing Network Security Configuration file.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
        {
           StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new 
           StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
           StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
  ....
  ....
  }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is my local context solution...

I have a Docker/Lando instance providing me an API from a Lumen Restful app, local domains are not working ("https://localhost:32769", "http://localhost:32770", "http://wxyz.lndo.site", "https://wxyz.lndo.site"), however, when I check the network IP using "ifconfig" in the terminal I could access using that IP

```
$ ifconfig
```

You must add a new parameter to your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

I use this **network_security_config.xml** file for local debugging

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user" overridePins="true"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

I use user-permissions as well

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

to your manifest application

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
```

hope it helps