# How to access localhost (wampserver) on Android emulator via android studio

Tags: android, mysql, wampserver

I have developed small app after watching a tutorial on how to connect MYSQL database with android apps. I have been testing this app on android emulator, but so far I haven't figured out whats going wrong.
I have searched the whole stackoverflow over this issue, but no success so far.
Stackoverflow contains solutions like '`using 10.0.2.2:8080`', '`using your own ip address`', '`switching off firewall settings`', '`changing apache server (configuration) settings`' and many more, but none of them have worked for me.

Here's my code:
BackgroundWorker.java

```
package apps.harry.mysqldemo;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
 * Created by harry on 18/11/2017.
 */
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    Log log;
    int a=0;
    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2:8081/login.php";
        if(type.equals("login")) {
            try {
                a=1;//for debugging purposes

                String user_name = params[1];
                String password = params[2];

                URL url = new URL(login_url);

                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();// this line seems to be some problem as during debugging it never crossed this line and hence you will see in logcat "erro is beacuse null 1", not "2"
                a=2;//for debugging purposes
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null)
                {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //a=3;
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
        log.e("onpostexecute","bg");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    log.e("onpostexecute","erro is beacuse "+result+" "+a);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package apps.harry.mysqldemo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    EditText uname_et,pass_et;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        uname_et=findViewById(R.id.uname_et);
        pass_et=findViewById(R.id.pass_et);

    }

    public void onLogin(View view)
    {
        String user_name=uname_et.getText().toString();
        String pass_word=pass_et.getText().toString();
        String type="login";

        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker=new BackgroundWorker(this);
        backgroundWorker.execute(type,user_name,pass_word);
    }
}
```

During the debugging process i found out these lines in logcat, have a look:

```
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
11-20 17:55:10.604 6165-6189/apps.harry.mysqldemo W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /10.0.2.2:8081
11-20 17:55:10.604 6165-6189/apps.harry.mysqldemo W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:143)
11-20 17:55:10.604 6165-6189/apps.harry.mysqldemo W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
11-20 17:55:10.604 6165-6189/apps.harry.mysqldemo W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
11-20 17:55:10.604 6165-6189/apps.harry.mysqldemo W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
11-20 17:55:10.604 6165-6189/apps.harry.mysqldemo W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
11-20 17:55:10.604 6165-6189/apps.harry.mysqldemo W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
11-20 17:55:10.604 6165-6189/apps.harry.mysqldemo W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
11-20 17:55:10.604 6165-6189/apps.harry.mysqldemo W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
11-20 17:55:10.604 6165-6189/apps.harry.mysqldemo W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
11-20 17:55:10.604 6165-6189/apps.harry.mysqldemo W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:258)
11-20 17:55:10.605 6165-6189/apps.harry.mysqldemo W/System.err:     at apps.harry.mysqldemo.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(BackgroundWorker.java:54)
11-20 17:55:10.605 6165-6189/apps.harry.mysqldemo W/System.err:     at apps.harry.mysqldemo.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(BackgroundWorker.java:25)
11-20 17:55:10.605 6165-6189/apps.harry.mysqldemo W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
11-20 17:55:10.605 6165-6189/apps.harry.mysqldemo W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
11-20 17:55:10.606 6165-6189/apps.harry.mysqldemo W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
11-20 17:55:10.606 6165-6189/apps.harry.mysqldemo W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
11-20 17:55:10.606 6165-6189/apps.harry.mysqldemo W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
11-20 17:55:10.606 6165-6189/apps.harry.mysqldemo W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
11-20 17:55:10.747 6165-6165/apps.harry.mysqldemo E/onpostexecute: erro is beacuse null 1
```

and, not only `Failed to connect to /10.0.2.2:8081`, it also failed to connect
`Failed to connect to /localhost:8081` and `Failed to connect to /192.168.0.5:8081`

I am really out of solutions. I don't know what to do.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

the error indicates **that you're not using a Network Security Configuration** as specified [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41334476/2494123) and to configure add Security Configuration File and include an entry in the manifest of your app to point to this file as specified in https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html#manifest it also show how to configure certificate authority (CAs) for debugging