# When i try to call webservice for login so login is failed

Tags: java, android

When I try to login through dotnet Web Service then it throw this error

```
03-15 17:15:28.899 29517-29959/com.example.welcom.abhinav
I/httpTransportSE: org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE@76bc3be 03-15
17:15:28.903 29517-29959/com.example.welcom.abhinav
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using
platform default 03-15 17:15:29.050
29517-29959/com.example.welcom.abhinav I/messge: false
```

This is xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.welcom.abhinav.MainActivity">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/loc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Location"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/signin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sign In" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

This class from which we can hit the web service from android application

```
package com.example.welcom.abhinav;

import android.util.Log;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

/**
* Created by welcom on 15-03-2018.
*/

public class WebService {
    private static String NAMESPACE="http://tempuri.org/";
    private static String URL ="http://www.getcodify.in/webservice.asmx";
    private static String SOAP_ACTION="http://tempuri.org/";

    public static  Boolean invokeHelloWorldWS(String user,String pass, String location,  String webMethName)
    {
        Boolean loginStatus=false;
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);

        PropertyInfo userPI=new PropertyInfo();
        PropertyInfo passPI=new PropertyInfo();
        PropertyInfo locationPI=new PropertyInfo();

        userPI.setName("user");
        userPI.setValue(user);
        userPI.setType(String.class);
        Log.i("user",user);
        passPI.setName("pass");
        passPI.setValue(pass);
        passPI.setType(String.class);
        Log.i("pass",pass);
        locationPI.setName("location");
        locationPI.setValue(location);
        locationPI.setType(String.class);
        Log.i("location",location);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapSerializationEnvelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapSerializationEnvelope.dotNet=true;
        soapSerializationEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE=new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        Log.i("httpTransportSE",httpTransportSE.toString());
        try{
            httpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION+webMethName,soapSerializationEnvelope);
            SoapPrimitive response= (SoapPrimitive) soapSerializationEnvelope.getResponse();
            loginStatus=Boolean.parseBoolean(response.toString());
            Log.i("messge",loginStatus.toString());

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MainActivity.errored=true;
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return loginStatus;
    }
}
```

this the main activity class of the application in we can call the webservice.class

```
   package com.example.welcom.abhinav;

   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.AsyncTask;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.ProgressBar;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button logIn;
    EditText location;
    EditText emailEt;
    EditText passEt;
    TextView disLoc;
    TextView disEm;
    TextView disPass;
    Boolean displayLocation;
    String displayEmail;
    String displayPassword;
    String loc;
    String em;
    String pass;
    static Boolean errored=false;
    //ProgressBar progressBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        location=findViewById(R.id.loc);
        emailEt=findViewById(R.id.email);
        passEt=findViewById(R.id.password);
        logIn=findViewById(R.id.signin);

        disLoc=findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        disEm=findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        disPass=findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        logIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (location.getText().length() != 0 && location.getText().toString() != "" ||
                        emailEt.getText().length() != 0 && emailEt.getText().toString() != ""||
                        passEt.getText().length() != 0 && emailEt.getText().toString() != "") {

                        loc=location.getText().toString();
                        em=emailEt.getText().toString();
                        pass=passEt.getText().toString();

                        AsyncCallWS task=new AsyncCallWS();
                        task.execute();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill all fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String,Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
           //disLoc.setText(displayLocation);


            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            if(!errored)
            {
                if(displayLocation)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Succesful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Failed, Try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error occured in invoking webservice", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            errored=false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            displayLocation=WebService.invokeHelloWorldWS(em, pass, loc,"Login");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933345/no-network-security-config-specified-using-platform-default

Comment: so whats the error

Answer (score 0):

Change your used URLs from http to https.

Comment: not working....