# "How to fix this post HTTP request using Android Studio?"

Tags: java, android, android-networking

I'm trying to post HTTP request to my web application. But there is no action done. Where am I wrong?

```
class AsyncT extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
        try{
            String url1 = "http://172.26.1.1/data/omnidrive";
            URL url = new URL(url1);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = 
            (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            String data = "[0.10,0.00,0.00]";

            DataOutputStream wr = new           
            DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(data);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I expected the data to be updated in the web application.

This is what it shows after I clicked the button

**Error**

> W/Settings: Setting device_provisioned has moved from android.provider.Settings.Secure to android.provider.Settings.Global.
>   V/HiTouch_HiTouchSensor: User setup is finished.
>   D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
>   I/ViewRootImpl: jank_removeInvalidNode all the node in jank list is out of time

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933345/no-network-security-config-specified-using-platform-default-android-log

Answer (score 2):

- Try this one might help you.
- First of create one Folder under res folder named it `xml` then in that folder create one xml file name `network_security_config`.
- Then Add below lines of code in that xml file.

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <network-security-config>
      <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
          <domain includeSubdomains="true">your url</domain>
      </domain-config>
  </network-security-config>
  ```
- Then below line in application tag in Manifest file.

  ```
  android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use should declare `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` inside XML `application` tag. It is used to indicate whether the app intends to use cleartext network traffic, such as cleartext HTTP.
For more information, please visit this site:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic